# PHP - Update news error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stacked with some problem with my edit button on some news site...Any type of help is welcome...
Here is my code..i will ignore irrelevant code

> admin_first.php

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id[] = (int) $row['id'];
        $header[] = htmlspecialchars($row['header']);
        $text[] = htmlspecialchars($row['text']);
        $picture[] = htmlspecialchars($row['pictures']);
        $date[] = $row['time'];
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($id); $i++)
        {
            echo '<div class="new_item"><h2>' . $header[$i] . '</h2><p class="text">' . $text[$i] . '</p><a href="' . $picture[$i] . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $picture[$i] . '"/></a><p class="time">' . $date[$i] . '</p></div>
                <div class="buttons"><form><input type="button" name="delete" id="delete" onclick="window.location.href=\'process_buttons.php?delete=' . $id[$i] . '\'" 
                    value="Obri�i vest"/><input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" onclick="window.location.href=\'process_buttons.php?edit=' . $id[$i] . '\'" value="Izmeni vest"/></form></div>';
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
```

and here is

> process_buttons.php

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
include 'constants.php';

is_logged_in("admin.php");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
$safe_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'delete', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(!empty($_GET['delete']))
{
    $query = "DELETE FROM news WHERE id='{$safe_id}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

    header("Location: admin_first.php");
}
else
{
```

?>

This is delete  part, that is working fine..

Problem is with this part here:

```
<?php   

$safe_id = (int) $_GET['edit']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='{$safe_id}'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $header = htmlspecialchars($row['header']);
    $text = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['text']));
    $picture = $row['picture'];
    header("Location: admin_first.php");

}
```

?>

thanks in advance...

Comment: what error you are getting? what is your question?

Comment: I simply cant process update ,it doesnt show any error to me , text that is processed earlier just stays untouched...

Comment: You select the record from the database and then just assign it's values to some variables and then you do a redirection, without any update..No values are going to change.

Comment: Please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this. Calling `htmlspecialchars` or casting to `int` is not a reliable escaping method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any update query and its execution part in your problem mentioned section. In that case,

You need to use update query to update your records into MySQL table.

Syntax is,

```
  Update tablename set columnname='value' where  id='value'
```